# How to make mitmproxy consider two requests as equal only looking at the URL?

Tags: http, xcode-ui-testing, mitmproxy

I'm doing a user iterface test for an application that needs data from an external server. I want to have a session (both with requests from my app and the server responses) stored in a file, so that next time I run the test, my app gets the response from this file.

For that purpouse I'm using mitmdump: when I want to save the traffic I run "mitmdump -w outfile", which works properly.

The problem comes when I try to use the reply mode, using "mitmdump -S fileName": My application's requests have cookies, tokens and session IDs included both in the body and the header lines that don't match with the saved ones, so mitmproxy fails.

My question is, is there any way of making mitmproxy match a request with one saved just looking at the url and ignoring all the other parameters?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are some options which can ignore content and parameters. You may try them with `server-reply`: `server_replay_ignore_content`, `server_replay_ignore_params` and `server_replay_ignore_payload_params`. More details https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/

Comment: I had seen that options, but when I try to call them I get: Error, unrecognized option.

Comment: Try to run options with mitmproxy command `mitmproxy --set server_replay_ignore_content=true`, or put options in `~/.mitmproxy/config.yaml`